# LINQ count Where 1 column has two int

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I am attempting to count the number of rows in a database using ASP.NET LINQ
The goal here is to:

```
 Select * from ChangeBoards WHERE status_id = 1 OR status_id = 3
```

Now lets assume the DB looks as such

```
id :  INT       
status _id INT  


id:1 status_id:1

id:2 status_id:3

id:3 status_id:2
```

using the below my output should be a count of 2. Why is it not?

```
var Open = db.ChangeBoards.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.status_id.Equals("1") || x.status_id.Equals("3")
                .ToList()
                .Count();
```

The above does not give any count. It always shows zero.

How do you count a table for rows that has specific data in columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
var Open = db.ChangeBoards.Count(x=> x.status_id == 1 || x.status_id == 3);
```

I believe comparing with `Equals` is not returning records.

Form your SQL Query it appears that `status_id` is of numeric type and you are first enumerating all rows in memory and then doing an object comparison *(using Equals)* between `status_id` and string `"1"`. That will always return false. Also that will require unnecessary resource usage, as it will first load your table in memory and then compare/calculate count.

Comment: Thank you Habib that was the issue. I over thought the query. sometimes its the easiest solution that become the hardest!

Comment: @Chris, you are welcome and it happens to all of us :)